# PHP mail() works in one situation and doesn't work in another

Tags: php, email

I have an userbase. Whenever a new user registers I send them a welcome email through php mail(). It works absolutely fine. Here is the mail part of the code-

```
$emailto = $useremail;
$toname = $username;
$emailfrom = 'hello@*****.com';
$fromname = '*****';
$subject = 'Welcome to ****';
$messagebody = 'Dear '.$name.'<br/><br/>Thank you for becoming a member in the family of <b>*******</b>.<br>Please enter your chosen <b>Username : '.$username.'</b> and the <b>Activation Code : '.$y.'</b> to complete your registration process.<br/><b/r> You can enter the details in the link: www.*****.com/reg_success.html<br/><b/r><b><i>The*****Team</b></i>';

$headers = 
    'Return-Path: ' . $emailfrom . "\r\n" . 
    'From: ' . $fromname . ' <' . $emailfrom . '>' . "\r\n" . 
    'X-Priority: 3' . "\r\n" . 
    'X-Mailer: PHP ' . phpversion() .  "\r\n" . 
    'Reply-To: ' . $fromname . ' <' . $emailfrom . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n" . 
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $params = '-f ' . $emailfrom;
$test = mail($emailto, $subject, $messagebody, $headers, $params);
```

But almost the same mail() code, which I am using for sending a password reset link. Is not working. Although the code is not throwing an error, the mails are not getting delivered. I have checked that registration mails are working perfect and fast. Not over here. here is the code

```
   $pwrurl = "www.*****.com/reset_password.php?q=".$*****;
    $emailto = '$useremail';
    $toname = '$username';
    $emailfrom = 'hello@****.com';
    $fromname = '****';
    $subject = 'Password Change Request';
    $messagebody = 'Dear '.$name.'<br/><br/>We received a request to reset the <b> login password  </b> of your account. <br/>If you have not made the request, please call us immediately as someone else might be trying to access your account. <br> If you have indeed requested the reset, please click on the following link to reset your login password: <br/>'.$pwrurl.'</br>Remeber the link will remain active for an hour.<br/><b/r><b><i>****</b></i>';

    $headers = 
        'Return-Path: ' . $emailfrom . "\r\n" . 
        'From: ' . $fromname . ' <' . $emailfrom . '>' . "\r\n" . 
        'X-Priority: 3' . "\r\n" . 
        'X-Mailer: PHP ' . phpversion() .  "\r\n" . 
        'Reply-To: ' . $fromname . ' <' . $emailfrom . '>' . "\r\n" .
        'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n" . 
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $params = '-f ' . $emailfrom;
   $test = mail($emailto, $subject, $messagebody, $headers, $params);
```

Comment: So, you are saying, same code is working for registration but not for password rest. Right ?

Comment: Almost the same code as you can see above

Comment: there is difference between **almost same** and **same**.

Comment: Is it getting sent to the Spam folder

Comment: No it is not. I have checked.

Comment: @soumyajyoti do upvote and accept the answer, if it solves your problem

Comment: already upvoted

Comment: @soumyajyoti You are supposed to accept answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

It is because of, in second code.

```
$emailto = '$useremail';
$toname = '$username';
```

where as in your first code

```
$emailto = $useremail;
$toname = $username;
```